# Pass the name of a variable to a function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pretty-print

I'm trying to create a printing function. I want it to be able to take in a list of variables and print out both **their value and their name**. So far, I have the following code:

```
std::ostream& debug_values(std::ostream& out);  

template <typename V, typename... R>
std::ostream& debug_values(
    std::ostream& out, const V& value, const R&... remaining) {
  out << value << ", ";
  debug_values(out, remaining...);
  return out;
}
```

This works, but it only prints out the values. For example:

```
ostream out;
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;
debug_values(out, i1, i2) //Will print 1, 2
```

Instead, I would like debug_values to print out the following:

```
debug_values(out, i1, i2); //i1: 1, i2: 2
```

Is there a way to do this in C++? If so, how?

Comment: There is always the `#`macro way...

Comment: Using macros is probably the only way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use pure C++ to achieve that. 
However you can use the preprocessor to achieve what you want

```
#define PP( expr ) std::cout<<#expr<<" "<<expr<<std::endl;
```

See it live here : http://ideone.com/UopOni

Alternatively, Qt's `QObject`s can have this kind of named variables called [properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/properties.html)

This solution is useful for debugging or logging, but it's not very pretty.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this in C++? If so, how?

No, you cannot do this, variable names aren't kept somehow when you are passing the variables as parameters.

---

It's not possible using plain c++ language, but the c-preprocessor can be used to create stringized (see the `#` operator) versions of your variable names, and use them for debug/logging output.

The drawback is, that you have to create versions of a possible `debug_values()` macro, that are resolved to a fixed number of given arguments (though IIRC there are macro metaprogramming libraries available, that support to implement such stuff easier).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this in C++? If so, how?

You can use a `std::map`.

```
ostream out;
int i1 = 1;
int i2 = 2;
std::map<std::string, int> values;
values["i1"] = i1;
values["i2"] = i2;

// Change debug_values to use the map as its second argument type
debug_values(out, values)
```

Is there a way to automate the creation of the `map`? I don't think there is.

Answer (score 0):

With MACRO, you may do

```
// (up to hard coded 6 arguments)
#define NARGS_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5 , _6, N, ...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define CAT_(a, b) a ## b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)

#define name_1(x)                     #x, x
#define name_2(x, x2)                 #x, x, #x2, x2
#define name_3(x, x2, x3)             #x, x, #x2, x2, #x3, x3
#define name_4(x, x2, x3, x4)         #x, x, #x2, x2, #x3, x3, #x4, x4
#define name_5(x, x2, x3, x4, x5)     #x, x, #x2, x2, #x3, x3, #x4, x4, #x5, x5
#define name_6(x, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6) #x, x, #x2, x2, #x3, x3, #x4, x4, #x5, x5, #x6, x6

#define names(...) CAT(name_, NARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define debug_values(out, ...) debug_values_impl(out, names(__VA_ARGS__))

std::ostream& debug_values_impl(std::ostream& out) { return out << std::endl; }
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
std::ostream&
debug_values_impl(std::ostream& out, const char* name, const T& value, const Ts&... args)
{
    out << name << ':' << value << ", ";
    return debug_values_impl(out, args...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34e0bbd5458d74a4)